# Hybris - How to add export import widget for customer in backoffice?

Tags: import, export, sap-commerce-cloud, backoffice

In backoffice there is a widget for export and import for Product.  With this functionality, a user can select what columns can be exported as described here.

I [read here](https://help.hybris.com/6.7.0/hcd/1763d14a7efb408fb37976b804fe7724.html) but doesn't specify how it can be configured on other Types, like Customer.

Is this something can be configured with other types?

Answer (score 4):

You can decide on which actions are available via *config.xml*. See the `<context type="Product" component="listviewactions">` for inspiration and define alike configuration for your type.

Answer (score 2):

You can add actions using in your `backoffice-config.xml` file. Cf. [Configuring UI in Backoffice](https://help.hybris.com/1811/hcd/596a74a0ee10418cb8203023e80432d8.html)

```
<context component="myListviewActions" type="Customer">
    <y:actions xmlns:y="http://www.hybris.com/cockpit/config/hybris">
        <y:group qualifier="common">
            <y:label>actiongroup.common</y:label>
            <y:action action-id="com.hybris.cockpitng.listview.action.export.csv" property="exportColumnsAndData" />
        </y:group>
    </y:actions>
</context>
```

Here is a list of some actions exemple :

```
<y:action action-id="com.hybris.cockpitng.action.delete" property="currentObject"/>
<y:action action-id="com.hybris.backoffice.widgets.actions.sync" property="currentObject"/>
<y:action action-id="com.hybris.cockpitng.action.flexibletoggle">
        <y:parameter>
            <y:name>viewMode</y:name>
            <y:value>hidden</y:value>
        </y:parameter>
        <y:parameter>
            <y:name>breakpoint</y:name>
            <y:value>m</y:value>
        </y:parameter>
</y:action>
<y:action action-id="com.hybris.cockpitng.action.create" property="pageable.typeCode">
        <y:parameter>
            <y:name>triggerContext</y:name>
            <y:value>pcmbackoffice</y:value>
        </y:parameter>
</y:action>
<y:action action-id="com.hybris.cockpitng.listview.action.export.csv" property="exportColumnsAndData"/>
<y:action action-id="com.hybris.cockpitng.action.edit" property="selectedObjects" triggerOnKeys="^e">
        <y:parameter>
            <y:name>forwardSelectionToSocket</y:name>
            <y:value>selectedItemsToEdit</y:value>
        </y:parameter>
        <y:parameter>
            <y:name>forwardSelectionAs</y:name>
            <y:value>list</y:value>
        </y:parameter>
</y:action>
```

There are more you can find exemple with a research in your workspace.

Comment: Adding the <context> element to the custom config file doesn't do anything.  I also ran Hybris update after the building. I assume this will require some code modification as well.  Is that the case?

Comment: @3a6f Make sure that your widget references the component of the context tag for the actionSlotComponentId. See https://help.hybris.com/1811/hcd/8b80155586691014b8a180a42610cdbc.html for more details (search for Actions Toolbar Configuration)

Answer (score 1):

My knowledge Excel import/export only for products in OOTB. Maybe you can make custom development for it or use below OOTB functionality:

- Impex import/export from hac
- Rest service
- Export to CSV button below to list (it is only export view data).
- Use import cockpit if your version support